# Word 2007 pauses and displays an hourglass with every keystroke while editing an shared doc

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, sharepoint

Word 2007 pauses and displays an hourglass with every keystroke while editing a shared doc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sit closer together?  ...

Comment: Do you have more information, e.g. has this always happened? Does it only happen on your computer? Does other software on your computer run fine?

Comment: It happens occasionally, on and off, with no changes to what is installed on the computer. Being that I am editing a document on a sharepoint server, I suspect that it is network related. Other software and computer in general works fine. The problem goes away (and returns) on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the document out to your Shared Drafts folder.  Then your changes are made locally and only when you hit save does the new copy go back to the library.